# NGINX whitelist internal docker IP

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a server that runs 2 docker containers, a Node.js API container, and an NGINX-RTMP container. The server itself also uses NGINX as a reverse proxy to sort traffic between these two containers based on port.

The NGINX-RTMP server accesses the API server via it's network alias like so:

```
on_publish http://api-server:3000/authorize
```

Which works great to communicate container-to-container. I can also go the other way by using urls like

```
http://nginx-server:8080/some-endpoint
```

Now I have a route on the `NGINX` server that I would like to restrict to just local traffic (i.e. only the API server should be able to hit this location). Now normally I can do this with a simple

```
# nginx conf file
location /restricted {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
```

What I would *like* to do is something like this:

```
# nginx conf file
location /restricted {
    allow api-server;
    deny all;
}
```

But I need to use the actual IP of the container. Now I can get the IP of the container by inspecting it, and I see the IP is `172.17.0.1`. However when I look at other instances of this server I see some servers are `172.18.0.1` and `17.14.0.2` so it's not 100% consistent across servers. Now I could just write out all 256 variations of `172.*.0.0/24` but I imagine there must be a 'proper' way to wildcard this in nginx, or even a better way of specifying the container IP in my NGINX conf file. The only information I have found so far is to modify the type of network I'm using for my containers, but I don't want to do that.

How do I properly handle this?

```
# nginx conf file
location /restricted {
    allow 172.*.0.0/24;
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have solved this one on my own actually.

Originally I thought I could `172.0.0.1/8` the block to allow all the IPs I thought possible for the local network, but this is wrong.

After reading this article: https://www.arin.net/reference/research/statistics/address_filters/ ([archive mirror](https://archive.is/wip/fHxCb))

> According to standards set forth in Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) document RFC-1918 , the following IPv4 address ranges are reserved by the IANA for private internets
>
> 10.0.0.0/8 IP addresses: 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255
>
> 172.16.0.0/12 IP addresses: 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
>
> 192.168.0.0/16 IP addresses: 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255

Notice that the `172` net is a `/12` and not `/8`.

Which is explained as

> In August 2012, ARIN began allocating “172” address space to internet service, wireless, and content providers.

So I believe the correct method is:

```
# nginx conf file
location /restricted {
    allow 172.16.0.0/12;
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: actually, this directive opens nginx worldwide

Comment: @vladkras how so?

Comment: 172.16.... in docker stack covers all ips of all containers, which usually means there’re no restrictions at all

Comment: Yes, but that was the goal, for intra-system containers to be able to make NGINX requests, but to block all requests from external machines

Comment: But it's not just intra-system containers! Your docker host is also mapped into that ip range, at least if you use docker-compose. I just tried it. `allow 172.16.0.0/12;` allows connections from a different PC into my docker containers.